# access json fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am  trying to access field of json respose :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './get_data_json.php',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response['time']);
      console.log(response['0']['key'])
    }

});
```

The get_data_json.php file is like this:-

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
$str = file_get_contents('./data.json');
echo $str;
?>
```

and the data.json file is like:-

```
{"time":"08\/11\/2017 11:10:01 am","0":{"key":"\u3075\u308b\u3055\u3068\u7d0d\u7a0e","doc_count":31626,"old_count":25737},"1":{"key":"\u5b89\u5ba4\u5948\u7f8e\u6075","doc_count":19526,"old_count":13778},"2":{"key":"\u9001\u6599\u7121\u6599","doc_count":18881,"old_count":14411},"3":{"key":"\u3010\u8a33\u3042\u308a\u3011","doc_count":13415,"old_count":7770},"4":{"key":"\u5b89\u5ba4\u5948\u7f8e\u6075 finally","doc_count":12593,"old_count":13778},"5":{"key":"\u30ef\u30f3\u30d4\u30fc\u30b9","doc_count":9516,"old_count":9203},"6":{"key":"\u798f\u888b","doc_count":8998,"old_count":5867},"7":{"key":"\u30cb\u30c3\u30c8","doc_count":8906,"old_count":9443},"8":{"key":"\u30af\u30ea\u30b9\u30de\u30b9","doc_count":8240,"old_count":4913},"9":{"key":"\u3010\u25ce\u3011","doc_count":7245,"old_count":7742},"10":{"key":"\u5317\u6b27","doc_count":7190,"old_count":6844},"11":{"key":"\u30b9\u30cc\u30fc\u30d4\u30fc","doc_count":6971,"old_count":5019},"12":{"key":"\u30c7\u30a3\u30ba\u30cb\u30fc","doc_count":6590,"old_count":5878},"13":{"key":"\u3010\u30d0\u30fc\u30b2\u30f3\u672c\u3011","doc_count":6398,"old_count":4536},"14":{"key":"\u52a0\u6e7f\u5668","doc_count":6393,"old_count":4850},"15":{"key":"\u30af\u30ea\u30b9\u30de\u30b9\u30c4\u30ea\u30fc","doc_count":6346,"old_count":4972},"16":{"key":"\u30d5\u30a1\u30fc","doc_count":6268,"old_count":5487},"17":{"key":"\u30a2\u30a6\u30c8\u30ec\u30c3\u30c8","doc_count":6057,"old_count":5305}}
```

The response for console.log(response) is:-

```
{"time":"08\/11\/2017 11:10:01 am","0":{"key":"\u3075\u308b\u3055\u3068\u7d0d\u7a0e","doc_count":31626,"old_count":25737},"1":{"key":"\u5b89\u5ba4\u5948\u7f8e\u6075","doc_count":19526,"old_count":13778},"2":{"key":"\u9001\u6599\u7121\u6599","doc_count":18881,"old_count":14411},"3":{"key":"\u3010\u8a33\u3042\u308a\u3011","doc_count":13415,"old_count":7770},"4":{"key":"\u5b89\u5ba4\u5948\u7f8e\u6075 finally","doc_count":12593,"old_count":13778},"5":{"key":"\u30ef\u30f3\u30d4\u30fc\u30b9","doc_count":9516,"old_count":9203},"6":{"key":"\u798f\u888b","doc_count":8998,"old_count":5867},"7":{"key":"\u30cb\u30c3\u30c8","doc_count":8906,"old_count":9443},"8":{"key":"\u30af\u30ea\u30b9\u30de\u30b9","doc_count":8240,"old_count":4913},"9":{"key":"\u3010\u25ce\u3011","doc_count":7245,"old_count":7742},"10":{"key":"\u5317\u6b27","doc_count":7190,"old_count":6844},"11":{"key":"\u30b9\u30cc\u30fc\u30d4\u30fc","doc_count":6971,"old_count":5019},"12":{"key":"\u30c7\u30a3\u30ba\u30cb\u30fc","doc_count":6590,"old_count":5878},"13":{"key":"\u3010\u30d0\u30fc\u30b2\u30f3\u672c\u3011","doc_count":6398,"old_count":4536},"14":{"key":"\u52a0\u6e7f\u5668","doc_count":6393,"old_count":4850},"15":{"key":"\u30af\u30ea\u30b9\u30de\u30b9\u30c4\u30ea\u30fc","doc_count":6346,"old_count":4972},"16":{"key":"\u30d5\u30a1\u30fc","doc_count":6268,"old_count":5487},"17":{"key":"\u30a2\u30a6\u30c8\u30ec\u30c3\u30c8","doc_count":6057,"old_count":5305}}
```

and I am getting message for 
response['time']  =  undefined
response['0']['key'] = undefined

Comment: Try to console.log(response). Is it JSON or string in your case?

Comment: If it's string- just do `response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh - JSON is a string ... did you mean to ask is it a javascript object or a string

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it's right.

Comment: simply add `resonse=JSON.parse(response);` just after `function(response) {` - the rest of your code should be fine

Comment: What do you mean by JSON is a string? http://www.json.org/ JSON is just an object notation. it can be inside the string, but itself it's not a string.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh - *JSON is a text format* ... that's a string

Comment: Ok it got what you’re saying. Sorry :) it’s kind of confusin sometimes

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Thanks @VitaliiChmovzh and @JaromandaX `JSON.parse(response);` worked.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the article!